# SQL Query to find Products Association

Tags: sql, hana

I have a Table with Invocie Data (100624357 records) like:

```
Invoice Number   Product Number   Quantity   Price   Amount
-----------------------------------------------------------
I0001            P0001            10         10      100
I0001            P0002            10         10      100
I0001            P0003            10         10      100
I0002            P0001            10         10      100
I0002            P0002            10         10      100
I0003            P0001            10         10      100
I0003            P0003            10         10      100
```

If Product A and Product B are in the same Invoice then they have 1 association. So I want to find out all the associations between different products like:

```
Product A    Product B    Association
-------------------------------------
P0001        P0002        20%
P0001        P0003        20%
P0002        P0003        10%
```

Can some one guide me how to get this association in most efficient way because the data set is very big.

Thanks and best regards.

Fahad

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the SAP HANA Business Function Library (BFL) for this basket analysis.

There's extensive example and tutorial information available on scn.sap.com, e.g. http://scn.sap.com/community/predictive-analysis/blog/2014/12/24/basket-analysis-with-sap-predictive-analysis-and-sap-hana--part-1

- Lars